# How to generate charts with arrows?

Tags: arrows, charts, relation-symbols

Recently, I discovered LaTeX and started working with it. Currently, I´m able to create simple summaries, etc. with formulas, lists, etc. Although LaTeX is still really new for me.
Anyway, now I would like to create a chart with a structure similar to this one:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a6/Systemarchetyp09.png

My topic is an economic one, but I guess that doesn´t matter regarding the things I´d like to know.
So it is basically about creating those arrows, especially the concave ones. And also the remarks written next to those arrows and the boxes around the connected elements.
I guess a specific package has to be implemented to get this done?

If anybody could help me, I´d really appreciate it ;-)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  I think you should start by having a look at the [`tikz` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  You will find many examples of its use on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here something that seems to be reasonably close to your example, made with `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, pdf, x11names]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{helvet} 
% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand\framenode[2]{\Rnode{#1}{\psframebox{#2}}}
\newcommand\frameboxnodes[2]{\psDefBoxNode{#1}{#2}}%{\psframebox{#2}}}%
\usepackage{makebox} 
\usepackage{stackengine} 


\begin{document}

\psset{framearc=.2,framesep =3pt,arrows =->, arrowinset = 0,arrowsize = 8pt}
\sffamily\itshape\boldmath
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.2, colsep=1.8,mnode = r]% defines the distance between two frames
    & \framenode{kum}{\Centerstack{kumulierte Nutzung {\color{red}kritisch~?}}} 
    \\[-1.8cm]
    \framenode{durA}{\Centerstack{Nutzung durch~A}} &  & \Rnode{durB}{\psframebox{\Centerstack{Nutzung durch~A}}}%
    \\
     [name = O1] & [name = C]\pscircle[linewidth = 3pt](C){0.5}\psframebox[fillstyle = solid, linestyle = none, framesep = 2pt]{\color{red}überkritisch}  & [name = O2]
     \\
    \framenode{furA}{\Centerstack{\makebox*{Nutzung}{Nutzen} für~A}} &  & \framenode{furB}{\Centerstack{\makebox*{Nutzung}{Nutzen} für~B}} \\[-1.5cm]
    & \framenode{kurz}{\color{red}\Centerstack{kurzzeitige Übernutzung}}
     \upshape
     \psarcn(O1){2.3}{-113}{113} \uput{1.67}[128](O1){(+)}
     \psarcn(O1){2.3}{67}{-67}\uput{1.67}[-52](O1){(+)}
     \psarc(O2){2.3}{113}{-113} \uput{1.67}[-128](O2){(+)}%
     \psarc(O2){2.3}{-67}{67}\uput{1.67}[52](O2){(+)}
     \ncline{durA}{kum}\ncline{durB}{kum}
     \ncline[nodesepB=0.25]{-}{kum}{C}\ncline[nodesepA=0.25]{-}{C}{kurz}
     \color{red}\psset{linecolor = red, npos = 0.6,labelsep = 1pt}
     \ncline{kurz}{furA}\nbput{(--)}\ncline{kurz}{furB}\naput{(--)}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]